# Adding custom field to Ubercart Invoice

Tags: drupal, ubercart

My client has an ubercart based shop which works fine. Due to some internal stuff he needs to manually add a field to each invoice. I wanted to know if or rather how i can add a custom field to orders that gets displayed on all the invoices.

Comment: Does this field require input from the user, or from administrators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an old question but this may help others; you can use the following code.

First checkout the  `customer.itpl.php` or `customer.itpl.php` files located under `ubercart/uc_order/templates`.

Then you can edit the foreach loop that echoes all the products and add your own fields this way:

```
<?php
     foreach ($order->products as $product) {
         $nid = ($product->nid);
         $noderef = node_load($nid);
         echo $product->title .' : '.$noderef->your_own_field[0]['value'];
         echo "<br />";
?>
```

My Ubercart installation has the product fields can be edited from  `http://www.mysite.com/admin/content/node-type/product/fields`.

You can find more information on [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1207938).

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally had to make this change, so I'm not speaking from experience, but looking at the documentation I would try the following: (you could cut corners and avoid some work by modifying the existing modules, but this is the cleanest way I can think of)

1. create a module that stores your field and the the order number.
2. using from_alter modify the invoice editing screen to give your users a way to edit the field.
3. use the invoice template to pull in your field, based on the order number. [invoice "system" documentation](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/246/invoice_system).

It's not a simple change, but using this pattern you'll get the modification you are looking for without having to worry about updates not working.

Comment: Thanks… that might be a way to get this done. Will try it out next week.

Comment: did this answer work for you? totally forgot about following up, and sure could use the bounty :)